# Ignore test cases while running maven project with sonar

Tags: maven, sonarqube

I have installed sonar and trying to analyze maven based application using following command :

```
clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Psonar  sonar:sonar
```

still its executing test-cases.

What if I doesn't want the analysis of unit test cases?

Comment: Why wouldn't you want your test code to be analysed too? Test code is part of the production code and is at least as important - making your tests better is a very easy way of adding more value to your application.

Comment: Well right now I have upgraded lot of functionality without executing unit test-cases. So current version of unit-test cases are not executable... That's why I need to skip them while sonar analyze the application.

Comment: So how do you know your changes do the job & don't break anything? That's the whole idea of the tests - they prove that the app does what it says it does. Not keeping the tests current simply removes any value they ever had, and makes your job a lot harder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the solution, added `-DskipTests=true` with maven command.

The full command which works for me is :

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests=true -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true sonar:sonar
-Dsonar.database=mysql
-Dsonar.jdbc.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver -Dsonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mvn sonar:sonar -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

is also an option, but make sure that your unit tests ran before to have results for unit test coverage in sonar